# Twitter Bootstrap grid and _slightly_ uneven cell height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I'm trying to code a simple grid of thumbnails with the Bootstrap grid system. What I want to have is a common, matrix-style look, with all the cells having the same width and height. Note that *I don't want to achieve the effect of having a look with uneven cell heights such as Masonry does*.

Cells are filled with images. The images are supposed to be all of the same size but, unfortunately, they can be *slightly* different in height (a question of a handful of pixels, often just one). All images, though, have exactly the same width.

Cells which are taller "eat" space from the cell of the row below, that is rendered empty. The problem can be seen here:

http://www.bootply.com/fabriziogiudici/FdYVizMPCC

For instance, the thumbnail "San Francisco and surroundings" has the extra pixels and causes the cell immediately below to be empty.

Is it possible to fix this problem without changing the existing images and making no use of JavaScript?

Applying a min-height to img's can't be done, because the height is computed at runtime in function of the width (to preserve the image aspect ratio) and the width is computed in function of the available room.

The only solution that comes to my mind is to have each image stacked (e.g. by means of two stacked div's) with a transparent one taller than the tallest image; in this way, all the heights would be flushed, still they would be dynamically computed in function of the available width.

But before implementing this solution, I'd like to know whether there's a simpler solution based on CSS.

Thanks.

Edit: I'm adding a local copy of the ply for convenience:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="/themes/the-best-ones">
          <img alt="" src="http://stoppingdown.net/media/stillimages/20140517-0085/400/image.jpg">
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>The Best Ones</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="/themes/toscana">
          <img alt="" src="http://stoppingdown.net/media/stillimages/20130526-0309/400/image.jpg">
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>Toscana</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="/themes/bourgogne">
          <img alt="" src="http://stoppingdown.net/media/stillimages/20131118-0199/400/image.jpg">
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>Bourgogne</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="/themes/le-long-de-la-durance">
          <img alt="" src="http://stoppingdown.net/media/stillimages/20140501-0046/400/image.jpg">
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>Le long de la Durance</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="/themes/san-francisco-and-surroundings">
          <img alt="" src="http://stoppingdown.net/media/stillimages/20080510-0236/400/image.jpg">
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>San Francisco and surroundings</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="/themes/fog">
          <img alt="" src="http://stoppingdown.net/media/stillimages/20141020-0150/400/image.jpg">
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>Fog</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="/themes/paysages-du-rhone">
          <img alt="" src="http://stoppingdown.net/media/stillimages/20070629-0046/400/image.jpg">
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>Paysages du Rhône</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="/themes/liguria">
          <img alt="" src="http://stoppingdown.net/media/stillimages/20140209-0418/400/image.jpg">
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>Liguria</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="/themes/ceillac">
          <img alt="" src="http://stoppingdown.net/media/stillimages/20121016-0119/400/image.jpg">
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>Ceillac</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="/themes/flowers">
          <img alt="" src="http://stoppingdown.net/media/stillimages/20150516-0553/400/image.jpg">
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>Flowers</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="/themes/haute-vallee-de-l-ubaye">
          <img alt="" src="http://stoppingdown.net/media/stillimages/20120908-0195/400/image.jpg">
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>Haute vallée de l'Ubaye</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="/themes/orbetello">
          <img alt="" src="http://stoppingdown.net/media/stillimages/20140518-0266/400/image.jpg">
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>Orbetello</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="/themes/le-massif-des-maures">
          <img alt="" src="http://stoppingdown.net/media/stillimages/20141212-0013/400/image.jpg">
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>Le Massif des Maures</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

.thumbnail h3 {
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Use div's with background images instead of images?

Comment: I'm refactoring other parts of the website with  the div background approach, for responsive design (images are picked of different sizes in function of the screen size; it's where I used the stacked image trick that I hinted about). Responsive design is not needed in this case, but if it fixes the problem, it would be ok. Going to try it.

Comment: Have you considered using Jquery.machtHeight ? http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using div's with background images and using the ::after pseudo selector to achieve an appropriate aspect ratio.

http://www.bootply.com/BcioXulU4C

Comment: The linked ply doesn't work, anyway point taken. BTW: maybe just padding-bottom: 70% is enough? Tried here: http://www.bootply.com/uynKnjZrrJ - would it work cross-browser?

Comment: It doesn't work in what sense? And the browser support for the ::after selector can be found here: https://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/.

Comment: I see the grid with captions, but I can't see the images. Edit: with Chromium.